# Book text analysis tools

Tags: computational-linguistics, nlp, applied-linguistics

Is there any open source software to automatically extract information from a book: genre, style, location and time of the story, characters, etc?

Comment: I think this question concerns available software and the identification of books rather than linguistics per se.

Comment: In any case, I doubt it would be possible to infer information like those from a book in some automatic way... I can't see how that could be automatized. Andrey, do you mean extract information from a book or a database? Please include more detail in your question! :)

Comment: @Alenanno  Well, according to the answer to [this question](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1760/how-to-identify-character-names-in-a-body-of-text) it's at least possible to extract named entities from a running text; so it sounds like this larger task is conceptually possible.

Comment: @MarkBeadles What kind of sorcery is that??? :D I honestly didn't think it was possible, but you never stop learning. eheh :)

Answer (score 2):

This, generally speaking, corresponds to the fields of [text mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mining), [entity extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_mining), and [automated (meta)data extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction). It's not part of linguistics *per se*; it's more applied linguistics with relations to information science and library science.

It's an enormously important field right now: consider, for example, the [Google Books project](http://www.google.com/googlebooks/library.html). Google needs to be able to mine through thousands of scanned books to extract author, publisher, title, date, etc. so that it can create metadata to index the books with. [They don't solely use text mining to do this](http://support.google.com/books/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53549), but it is one of the methods. I don't know if these methods are good enough to find genre, characters, etc., but it's a similar idea.

If you're looking for software, I suggest starting with the [list of FOSS Information Extraction tools found in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction#Free_or_open_source_software_and_services) as a starting point.